# Slicer to Year and Month by Calendar table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have **two tables** in my datamodel. One about work permits and the another is about occupational accidents.

1. The table about **occupational accidents** has a date column that says **when the accident happened.**
2. The table about **work permits** has two date columns:

   2.1.One is about **when permission was requested**.

   2.2.Another one is about **when permission was granted.**

I want to create several charts for each one of my tables with an **slicer** about **year** and another one about **month.**

As a rule this is not a difficult work because Power-Bi creates you hierarchies with day, month, quarter and year, but **I'm using a DirectQuery NOT AN IMPORT QUERY** what means I can't make many changes in my table and PowerBi doesn't create me the hierarchy of date as usually it does.

So I thought about creating a new table which contains dates and join it with all the tables where I have a date field.

I'm relative new in PowerBi so I'm still finding out new things everyday. Yesterday I found the **CALENDARUTO() Expression** and I read a little about what It do and thought It could be work for what I want.

I made this:

```
CALENDARIO = 
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CALENDARAUTO();
        "Año"; YEAR([Date]);
        "Número de mes";MONTH([Date]);
        "Mes";SWITCH( MONTH ([Date]);
                12; "Diciembre";
                11; "Noviembre";
                10; "Octubre";
                 9; "Septiembre";
                 8; "Agosto";
                 7; "Julio";
                 6; "Junio";
                 5; "Mayo";
                 4; "Abril";
                 3; "Marzo";
                 2; "Febrero";
                 1; "Enero"
        );
        "Día del mes";DAY([Date]);
        "Trimestre";CEILING(MONTH([Date])/3;1)
    )
```

From what I understood, CALENDARAUTO() takes all the date values in your datamodel and creates a new table from there.

Then I created the relationship beetween my tables:

[image: Image relationship]

But this is not working as I thoughy, It takes me years where there is not any information neither in one nor in the another table so I don't undertand why It takes me 2012 as the Min date.

Besides, the total number by year or month does not match with the correct result.

**Is CALENDARAUTO() used to this kind of work?**

**Why is it not working?**

Comment: IMO, CALENDARAUTO() has too much 'automagical' behavior to be trusted.  It claims to look through all the fields in your model and identifies the earliest and latest dates, building all the rows in between them and thus guaranteeing a full set of rows covering every date in your model.  I would just use CALENDAR()  and specify your own start and end dates.  Pad it out by a few years, and odds are by that the time you need to do maintenance on it, these reports will be obsolete and forgotten anyhow.

Comment: I don't recommend calendar auto, you can have dates that you are not aware they exists in your model. This is what I recommend to build a date table.
https://blog.ladataweb.com.ar/post/185012464051/data-modeling-como-hago-una-tabla-fecha
Check DAX and Power Query options